# Seperate some values from json object (react , jquery)

Tags: jquery

In an application on react
I have this json data from `var product`

I am trying to store "**category names**" from below json

like

```
category: 'Jumpsuits,Cargo Jumpsuit' // this is the desired output

product = {
  "isConfigurableProduct": true,
  "id": "bdg-workwear-denim-boiler-suit",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 2437,
      "name": "Jumpsuits",
      "url_key": "jumpsuits",
      "level": 4,
      "url_suffix": ".html",
      "breadcrumbs": [
        {
          "category_id": 3,
          "category_level": 2,
          "category_name": "Clothing",
          "category_url_key": "clothing",
          "category_url_path": "clothing"
        },
        {
          "category_id": 82,
          "category_level": 3,
          "category_name": "Jumpsuits & Rompers",
          "category_url_key": "jumpsuits-rompers",
          "category_url_path": "clothing/jumpsuits-rompers"
        }
      ],
      "path": "clothing/jumpsuits-rompers"
    },
    {
      "id": 2492,
      "name": "Cargo Jumpsuit",
      "url_key": "cargo-jumpsuit",
      "level": 5,
      "breadcrumbs": [
        {
          "category_id": 3,
          "category_name": "Clothing",,
          "category_url_path": "clothing"
        },
        {
          "category_id": 82,
          "category_name": "Jumpsuits & Rompers",
          "category_url_path": "clothing/jumpsuits-rompers"
        },
        {
          "category_id": 2437,
          "category_name": "Jumpsuits",
          "category_url_key": "jumpsuits",
        }
      ],
      "path": "clothing/jumpsuits-rompers/jumpsuits"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is their any way i can separate it from this json ?
What would be the optimized way of fetching it ?
Any thoughts , appriciated

Comment: no thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate and push category names to a separate array and separate them.-

```
const product = {
    "isConfigurableProduct": true,
    "id": "bdg-workwear-denim-boiler-suit",
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 2437,
        "name": "Jumpsuits",
        "url_key": "jumpsuits",
        "level": 4,
        "url_suffix": ".html",
        "breadcrumbs": [
          {
            "category_id": 3,
            "category_level": 2,
            "category_name": "Clothing",
            "category_url_key": "clothing",
            "category_url_path": "clothing"
          },
          {
            "category_id": 82,
            "category_level": 3,
            "category_name": "Jumpsuits & Rompers",
            "category_url_key": "jumpsuits-rompers",
            "category_url_path": "clothing/jumpsuits-rompers"
          }
        ],
        "path": "clothing/jumpsuits-rompers"
      },
      {
        "id": 2492,
        "name": "Cargo Jumpsuit",
        "url_key": "cargo-jumpsuit",
        "level": 5,
        "breadcrumbs": [
          {
            "category_id": 3,
            "category_name": "Clothing",
            "category_url_path": "clothing"
          },
          {
            "category_id": 82,
            "category_name": "Jumpsuits & Rompers",
            "category_url_path": "clothing/jumpsuits-rompers"
          },
          {
            "category_id": 2437,
            "category_name": "Jumpsuits",
            "category_url_key": "jumpsuits",
          }
        ],
        "path": "clothing/jumpsuits-rompers/jumpsuits"
      }

    ]}

let sub_category_names = []
let category_names = []
product.categories.forEach(function (category) {
category_names.push(category.name)

 category.breadcrumbs.forEach(function (item) {
   sub_category_names.push(item.category_name)
});
});


 // for convert to string
let category_str = category_names.toString();
let str = sub_category_names.toString();
console.log("Main Categories are",category_str);
  console.log("Sub Cateogries are ",str);
```

Comment: It works, but how can i convert it to a simple string like "'Jumpsuits,Cargo Jumpsuit'"

Comment: I have updated my answer, kindly check it

Comment: You have loop through "breadcrumbs" that does not seems right. i want only category name. but not from breadcrumb

Comment: I don;t think there is anything wrong with it, category_name is object inside array of breadcrumbs, without loop through the array you cannot get the value

Comment: I have updated my, answer for both category and sub category names inside breadcrumb, if you don;t want category_name inside breadcrumb  just remove the second loop and sub_category_name array.

Comment: I am talking about "name" property in "categories": [
      {
        "id": 2437,
        "name": "Jumpsuits",

Comment: yes ! sorry about that I though category_name inside breadcrumb. I have done for the things, just  remove additional i.e.  category.breadcrumbs.forEach(function (item) {
   sub_category_names.push(item.category_name)
});

Comment: This was dynamic, how about adding a static key value pair in "category_names" ?

Comment: like this i.e. category.user_name= "john", this will add a static user_name with value "John" in categories object.