# getting problem in accessing the array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have following array and i want to be access the array as `temptype[product.ticketType].icon` where `product.tiketType` is the key of `temptype` array.

Based on this I want to return the value against that key.

```
temptype = [
    5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140: {
        _id: "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140",
        label: "test1",
        icon: "pi pi-arrow-down",
        color: "#ff0080",
        index: 0
    },
    5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d141: {
        _id: "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d141",
        label: "test1",
        icon: "pi pi-arrow-down",
        color: "#ff0080",
        index: 0
    }
]
```

Comment: check if this helps you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65803664/seperate-some-values-from-json-object-react-jquery/65803978#65803978

Comment: The array has invalid syntax. If you want to access by a key, use an object.

Comment: First of all you have to replace the `[` with `{` and the `]` with `}`. Then you can access the elements using something like that: `var product = {}; var product.ticketType = '5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140'; console.log(temptype[product.ticketType].icon);`

Comment: The number of problems that can be highlighted, solved or avoided just by a good IDE is pretty high. I would really suggest getting one, or adding/enabling linting if you don't have any already.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want an array for this, but first let's explain what's happening. There are probably two things going on:

1. Your array has non-index properties with the names `"5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140"` and `"5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d141"`. These are not array entries, they are extra properties. (Arrays can have non-entry properties, since they're objects.) Note that they are **strings**. That means that if `product.ticketType` is a *number*, using `temptype[product.ticketType]` won't find those properties, because `product.ticketType` will be converted to string using the default normal form, which is **decimal**, not hexadecimal.
2. The other problem is that those numbers are so huge that they're outside the range that JavaScript's `number` type (IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point) can accurately represent, even though they're integers. The max safe integer value¹ is `0x1fffffffffffff`, which is rather lower than `0x5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140`.

Use an object instead, and ensure that `product.ticketType` is maintained as a string, never converted to number, since (for instance) if you parse the string `"5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140"` as hex to a number, the result you get is not the same number (it's `0x5ffd7c785bb1140000000000` instead).

```js
const temptype = {
    "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140": {
        _id: "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140",
        label: "test1",
        icon: "pi pi-arrow-down",
        color: "#ff0080",
        index: 0
    },
    "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d141": {
        _id: "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d141",
        label: "test1",
        icon: "pi pi-arrow-down",
        color: "#ff0080",
        index: 0
    },
};
const product = {
    ticketType: "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d141",
};
console.log(temptype[product.ticketType].icon);
```

---

¹ *"max safe integer value"* In JavaScript, the maximum safe integer value is the value that you can reliably add one to and get a mathemetically-valid result. You can add `1` to ``0x1fffffffffffff`and get`0x20000000000000`, which is mathematically valid. (You don't have to remember that value, it's available as` Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.) **But**, if you add` 1`to`0x20000000000000`, you get...`0x20000000000000`again, which is not maethmatically valid. The reason is that as of`0x20000000000000`, IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point can only represent even numbers. (`0x20000000000000`+`2`gives you`0x20000000000002`). Go a lot further and it becomes limited to multiples of 4, and then multiples of 8, etc.

Comment: Awesome answer from a professional person

Answer (score 0):

```js
let temptype = {
    "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140": {
        _id: "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140",
        label: "test1",
        icon: "pi pi-arrow-down",
        color: "#ff0080",
        index: 0
    },
    "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d141": {
        _id: "5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d141",
        label: "test1",
        icon: "pi pi-arrow-down",
        color: "#ff0080",
        index: 0
    }
};

console.log(temptype["5ffd7c785bb1132298a3d140"].icon);
```

You need to convert it to a proper object so it can work like so! :D